# Using enum in json

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I am trying to execute the below code:

```
new UserTrackingConsumer().
    onMessage(new JSONObject(new UserTrackingMessage(UserTrackingEvent.ATC, "1230", 
    new Date(), "101", 10, "1.0.0", "android", "4.4", "test"))
    .toString());
```

where UserTrackingMessage constructor is:

```
public UserTrackingMessage(UserTrackingEvent userTrackingEvent, String customerId,
                Date dateTime, String productId, int quantity, String appVersion, 
                String device, String os, String property) {...}
```

and UserTrackingEvent is enum:

```
public enum UserTrackingEvent {

    PURCHASE("PURCHASE"), ATC("ATC");

    private String eventName;

    private UserTrackingEvent(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    } 
}
```

I am getting following error:

> Can not deserialize instance of com.test.UserTrackingEvent out of
>   START_OBJECT token

I tried all possible combinations of Json annotations but is unable to include the event in the expected Json.

Comment: The problem is that jackson can't instantiate an enum, which is what it is trying to do when you parse stuff and which of course cannot possibly work with an enum. So, I don't think there is a way to solve this with jackson. As a workaround maybe let the constructor take a string and do a UserTrackingEvent.valueOf(val) to figure out the enum value of that on your constructor and/or setter. That should allow jackson to simply pass in the string. You'll probably want to deal with the IllegalArgumentException that valueOf can throw somewhere.

Comment: @JillesvanGurp but how I will convert this Enum into JSON and vice versa

Comment: How is UserTrackingMessage defined?

Comment: @ShireResident it just has getter-setter for the fields mentioned in the constructor

Comment: to json might be doable, from json essentially impossible because jackson can't instantiate create new objects because enums don't work like that and jackson is probably not smart enough to figure out it needs to use the valueOf method. So the best advice is to not do that and instead make your model class that uses the enum smart enough to convert string values on the setter using valueOf.

Comment: @JillesvanGurp it has to be done using enum

Comment: So your onMessage() needs the JSON string representation of UserTrackingMessage? A sent a clarification on chat - could you check?

Comment: Thanks everyone. It is working now. Replacing JsonObject().toString() to ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString() worked for me.

Comment: @DeepikaRajani yep`JSONObject` has nothing to do with jackson. it is from `org.json` lib. as a side note: you still could combine and use both libs, just had to put  `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` above enum and add `@JsonCreator public static UserTrackingEvent fromObject(Map<String,String> data) { return UserTrackingEvent.valueOf(data.get("eventName")); }` in your enum, but you would also have problems with date format, so switching to full jackson serialization and deserialization is way better

Comment: @JillesvanGurp We are missing relevant code and the error message. Nevertheless, Jackson has thorough support for enums.